# Electron - download .zip file using ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, electron, node-request

I'm trying to build an Electron-based app, mostly using code from my existing web app. The electron version connects to my server and often relies on that online content. I am using Ajax requests (using Jquery) handle things like the user logging on, and a php session is created, which is required to access most of the content.

I am now trying to get Javascript to automatically download a .zip file and save it to a location, without the user doing anything. I failed to do this using an Ajax request, so have tried to use the Node.js 'request' module. Then however, it wouldn't download the file because it was not authorised (because the request creates a new session, different to the existing, logged-in one).

How can I get something like the following to work?

```
const fs = require("fs");

...

$.ajax({
  url: "my-server/file.zip",
  success: function (data) {
    fs.writeFile("local-file.zip", data);
  }
});
```

Note - I think it failed due to some issue with the way the downloaded data is encoded, but don't understand exactly what the problem was.

Alternatively, is it possible to use the existing ajax session in the request module, and download it that way?

Comment: Why not authorize the user using `request`, then download file?

Comment: I ideally don't want to a) authorise them when they log in, since they would rarely need to use this download feature so it seems inefficient, or b) in some way store their password for later authorisation when they attempt the download.If there is no easier approach possible I could try some version of this.

Comment: Tbh I think a better way is to move all your ajax requests to `request`.